# How to return a JSON Array from java server to ios app

Tags: java, ios, arrays, json, rest

I has an ios app which sends a http request to a REST service I have running on a local server. The server gets some information from the Twitter api and then sends it back to the ios app. I have put the data I want to send back in a JSONArray. How do I go about sending this array back as a response to the request.

I have included the method that receives the request and which initially sent back a string. I would like to change so it sends back the "returnedArray" array instead.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() throws JSONException {
        String convert = null;
        JSONArray returnedArray = new JSONArray();

        try {
            returnedArray = TweetUsingTwitter4jExample.getTweets();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convert;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to return the JSONArray as a string representation?

Comment: (Would be better to return it as a byte stream.)

Comment: @HotLicks would returning as a byte stream be a better way to do it if I wanted to turn it back into an array on the ios app.

Comment: Well, if you turn it into a String then it will be converted to 16-bit characters which will have to be crunched into 8-bit chars for transmission.  And the logic on the iOS end prefers to receive an NSData byte stream rather than an NSString 16-bit char string.  The most "natural" form for serialized JSON is a UTF8 series of bytes.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you, I'm going to try this out

Comment: @HotLicks if I'm sending the array as a byte stream, do I just send it using outputStream.write(); or can I still use the return statement. If I don't use the return statement will it still arrive at the same place on the ios app.

Comment: What you can use depends on what JSON kit you're using.  There are about 20 for Java, and I've given up trying to keep track of which do what.  A "proper" kit should include some scheme to produce a byte stream, but I don't know what the specifics would be.

Answer (score 0):

Call `toString()` on the JSONArray.

Comment: Thank you I had not thought of that. Will it be possible to change the string back into a JSON array on the other side, or will it lose its structure.